# Mocky IO response in console log not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, console.log

Before writing my code I would like to say that I have to be using Notepad ++ and a normal web  like chrome to get this to work. So through writing code in mocky io with the advanced mode (so adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `*`), then getting the link and placing it in my code I should get response in the console log.

Here is the code for you to see:

```
<html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript-Fetch</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            fetch('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5aa39fa3310000461026e28c').
                then(function(response){
                    console.log('response')


            })


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ahd what is the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase im getting errors instead of response in the console log like forbidden 403

Comment: Would you mind share the error you receive?

Comment: @NicoHaase failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 forbidden. Fetch api cannot load (mocky.io link) no access control origing header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Well, then there is a server returning an error message. Nothing you can solve in your application. Ask the provider of that URL why it returns such an error

Comment: @NicoHaase alright so I’ve tried everything, nothing works, trying it with localhost but it doesnt give me my codes in console log

Comment: What have you tried with localhost? And once again: if the server returns an error message, there's nearly nothing you can do about

Comment: @NicoHaase i’ve put my file in xampp htdocs folder and i got the response code in the console log, now i can’t do anything else all it shows is the response with {type  url etc}

Comment: I have a similar problem. Mocky io response with CORS error.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved my problem with mocky io using

```
https://cors.io/?http://www.mocky.io/v2/yourlink
```